# How to Configure the SAP Netweaver in Mac OS?

Tags: sap-gui

I tried as follows.  I gave Host number . But, the problem is with in the format of the connection.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this connection string:
/H/122.175.43.76/S/3266

Comment: Thanks a lot. Have been surfing for this solution